# converting from strings and integers... not sure what I am doing

Tags: python, string, numbers, integer, mixing

```
int_one =input("Please enter a three-digit number thats first number is greater than last  ")
int_one_swap = (int_one[-1]+int_one[1:-1]+int_one[0])
print (int_one_swap)

print (int(int_one) - int(int_one_swap))
math_one = (int(int_one)-int(int_one_swap))
print (math_one)
int_two_swap = (int(math_one[-1]+int(math_one[1:-1])+ int(math_one[0]))
print (int_two_swap)
final = (int_two_swap + math_one)
print (final)
if final == 1089:
    print ("Your result is 1089")
else:
    print ("Your result is not 1089 so your first and last digits must have differed by less than 2")
```

GETTING SYNTAX ISSUES. 
need to get program to run through all these commands and struggling to get it to work. Professor said something about conversions from integers and strings but I just don't get it. PLEASE HELP

Comment: 1. Please, format the code and 2) What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
int_one =input("Please enter a three-digit number thats first number is greater than last ") 
int_one_swap = (int_one[-1]+int_one[1:-1]+int_one[0]) 
print (int_one_swap)
print (int(int_one) - int(int_one_swap)) 
math_one = (int(int_one)-int(int_one_swap)) 
print (math_one) 
int_two_swap = int(int(str(math_one)[-1])+int(str(math_one)[1:-1])+ int(str(math_one)[0])) 
print (int_two_swap) 
final = (int_two_swap + math_one) 
print (final) 
if final == 1089: 
  print ("Your result is 1089") 
else: 
  print ("Your result is not 1089 so your first and last digits must have differed by less than 2")
```